# Saving images on files or on database when using docker

Tags: django, docker, devops, docker-swarm

I'm using docker for a project, the main focus for its usage is to make the application available even if one of the node (it's a 6 nodes cluster with `docker swarm`) is down.

The application is basically a Django App that can save some images from users and others models. I'm currently saving the images as files, but since I need to specify a `volume` locally for a single machine, I would like to know if it would be better to save the images on database cluster, so it would be available even if the whole node goes down. Or is there another way?

@Edit
Note: The cluster runs locally and doesn't have internet access

Comment: Yes, file-oriented storage in Docker isn’t the most scalable, especially once you get into multi-host setups; any sort of database-type setup is probably better.  You should be able to `docker rm` your containers freely and not lose anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options are two perform the file sharing via database or via the file system.

For file system sharing, you can use something like GlusterFS, so for each container it seems like they are mounting a host-local volume, but it's actually shared via GlusterFS between the hosts.

To my mind, if it's your application (e.g you can modify it at will), saving stuff in database would be the easier approach for most developers.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is often to go for a hosted option (such as [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)). Making a database resilient and highly available is really hard, and unless you are an expert on docker and mongo I would strongly recommend you to go for a hosted option.

Comment: The problem is that this cluster runs locally (internal network) and should not have access to the internet or any other external resource.

Comment: Ahh, yeah that explains it. Might be good to edit your question to include the requirement. But if it runs locally you can install the database locally and connect to it with the nodes running on docker.